# Upper bound on the norm of the inverse of matrices with zero limit

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\{L(\sigma)\}_{\sigma}$ be a family of matrices indexed by the parameter $\sigma$ so that the **operator norm** $||.||$ of $\{L(\sigma)\}_{\sigma}$ satisfies $Ae^{-a/\sigma}\leq ||L(\sigma)|| \leq Be^{-b/\sigma}$ as  $\sigma \to 0.$. All constants here are positive.

You can assume first that all $\{L(\sigma)\}_{\sigma}$ 's are invertible (if not, we take Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which always exists). Applying the fact $1=||I||\leq ||L(\sigma)||.||L(\sigma)^{-1}||$, we get a *lower* bound $\frac{1}{B}e^{b/\sigma}$ on $||L(\sigma)^{-1}||$ as $\sigma \to 0.$

My question is: how do get an **upper bound** $f(\sigma)$ on $||L(\sigma)^{-1}||$? Of course, $f(\sigma)\to \infty$ as $\sigma \to 0.$

Comment: Just considering diagonal matrices, the smallest diagonal element can be arbitrarily close to zero regardless of the operator norm.

Comment: @KeithMcClary sorry I couldn't follow that. Do you mind explaining a bit more in detail? I think (please correct me if I'm wrong) that every element of $L(\sigma)$ has to go to $0$, since the operator norm and hence equivalently, any matrix norm (all norms being equivalent for finite dimensional cases) has to go to zero. Hence $L(\sigma)\to O$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary  OR, are you saying that the condition on $L(\sigma)$ cannot hold to start with, i.e. no such $A,B,a,b$ exist with that double inequality written in the question?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but a lower bound on the operator norm does not say anything about how small the eigenvalues can be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hope for an upper bound. To spell out @Keith's comment, assume that $\|L(\sigma)^{-1}\|\le g(\sigma)$ for all such families. Then $g(\sigma)\ge\frac{e^{b/\sigma}}B$. Now consider the family
\begin{equation*}L(\sigma)=\begin{pmatrix}Be^{-b/\sigma}&0\\0&g(\sigma)^{-2}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}to arrive at a contradiction.